# Tradingview Json alerts

Tags: json, pine-script, indicator

I'm currently setting up my own alerts in TradingView, and I've seen alerts in another discord group whereby an alert based off 1 part of a cypher triggers an alert, but then that alert in discord also shows other variables from the cypher.

Can anyone explain or point me in the right direction as to how this is done? As I'd like to replicate this style on my own indicator alerts.

Initial assumption is some extra details need coding into the pinescript, but then I'd need to learn how to write the JSON alert to pull through the details and try to get it looking like the alert on the image provided.

Alert example:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000628599

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to build your json as you go through your script. An example would be for example:

```
var string jsonString = ""
jsonString :="['fixedData': 1, 'side': 'Short', 'price': " + str.tostring(close) + "]"
alert(jsonString, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

For the alert to be triggered and sent, you will then need to create an alert manually on your indicator (once it's finished) and choose in the conditions:

> Any alert() function call

You just need to put your [webhook data](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000529348), save and you should be getting the alert and the content on your server.